# changing the background image for different screen size using media query is not working on the smaller screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two different images. I am trying to use one of the images for small screens and the other on large screens sizes.

The image for the large screen size is displayed but that for the smaller screen size does not get displayed.

I think I am doing something wrong and hoping to find a solution.

index.html

```
<img loading="lazy" class="bg-big-image bg-small-image h-100" />
```

style.css

```
  .bg-big-image {
    background-image: url(path_to_image("211129_IKKS_LAETITIA_CASTA_02_060_V02_Mini@2x.jpg"));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .bg-small-image {
    background-image: url(path_to_image("Groupe de masques 20.jpg"));
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `path_to_image(...)` supposed to be, some sort of function? Then show what it does, and how it executes within a CSS file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the min-width in media screen to max-width because you define that second image only show on screen larger than 992px your css code should be like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 .bg-small-image {
   background-image: url(path_to_image("Groupe de masques 20.jpg"));
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
  }
}
```